# Conectar a base de datos PostgreSQL en fedora server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql, fedora

Estoy desarrollando un software en Visual Studio C# e intento conectarme a una base de datos PostgreSQL que levante en Fedora Server 32. La conexión lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
try
{
  string connection_string = "Server=192.168.1.7; Port=5432; User Id=postgres; Password=postgres; Database=postgres;";
  NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connection_string);
  connection.Open();
  MessageBox.Show("Conectado");
} catch (Exception x)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Se produjo un error: " + x.Message);
}
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error `Exception while connecting`. No se si estoy haciendo mal la conexión o será un problema del servidor ya que cuando inicio el servidor web (httpd) tampoco obtengo respuesta, pensé que talvez el firewall esta bloqueando las conexiones pero elimine todas las reglas del iptables y tampoco tengo conexión.

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo esta situacion la he tenido a continuacion le voy a cometar los pasos que he seguido.

1. Primero asegurarse que el servidor esta corriendo.

   # /etc/init.d/postgresql start

Paso # 1: Permitir que una direccion IP remota tenga acceso a  PostgreSQL

Necesita abrir el archivo nombrado /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf. Logearse como usuario postgres user usando el comando su command:

```
$ su - postgres
$ vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Nota: Puede usar el editor de texto de su preferencia.

Digamos que le gustaria dar acceso a a esta sub red 192.168.10.0/24, agregue esta linea.

```
host all all 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 trust
```

Ahora guarde y cierre el archivo.

Paso # 2: Permitir la comunicacion a trave del protocolo TCP/IP

Ahora necesita abrir el archivo de configuracion de PostgreSQL  /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf

```
$ vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

Ahora vamos a abrir y conectar TCP/IP puerto configurando tcpip_socket a true:

```
tcpip_socket = true
```

Busca la linea de configuracion que luce asi:

```
listen_addresses='localhost'
```

Proximo a las direcciones IP address(es) a escuchar; puede usar una lista de Ips separadas por comas; y el defaults es ‘localhost’, y ‘*’ es para todas las direcciones IP:

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

Guarde y cierre el archivo.

Paso # 3: Reiniciar el servidor PostgreSQL

Reiniciar el servidor PostgreSQL con el siguiente comando

```
# /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Esto va a abrir el puerto por defecto 5432.

Paso # 4: Probar su configuracion

Use  los commandos psql desde el cliente de esta manera:

```
psql -h PostgreSQL-IP-ADDRESS -U USERNAME -d DATABASENAME
```

Conectese al servidor remoto usando la direccion IP  192.168.10.5 y logearse usando un usuario de prueba desarrollador por ejemplo para conectarse a la base de datos Viajero:

```
$ psql -h 192.168.1.5 -U desarrollador -d Viajero
```

Donde,

```
-h 192.168.10.5 : Especifica la direccion IP o el nombre del host.

-U desarrollador : Se conecta a la base de datos con el usuario especificado en vez de usar el usuario por defecto. 

El usuario desarrollador debe tener los permisos necesarios para acceder a la base de datos.

-d Viajero : Especifica el nombre de la base de datos a la cual se quiere conectar.
```

Espero esto le permita acceder a su servidor.

Comment: No encuentro el `tcpip_socket` en el archivo postgresql.conf

Comment: intente en el archivo localizado aca  /etc/postgresql/[version]/main/postgresql.conf. 
Version: 9.1, 9.2, 9.3 ....

Comment: no existe esa ruta, la que me aparece es /etc/postgresql-setup/upgrade